# How can I clean out a CosmosDB from Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm building a piece of middleware where I take all open issues from one system and create tickets for such in a different system. Then when the issue gets closed in the first system, the middleware will close the ticket in the other system.

I receive a list of open issues from the first system daily. I put those into a CosmosDB (SQL) table, do some magic to them to open the tickets in the other system, then copy them to a historical store.
To be able to close tickets I'd like to empty the CosmosDB table so that any ticket *not* in the next daily load can be closed.

I tried setting up a DataFlow where I use the CosmosDB table as source, then select nothing and use the same CosmosDB table as sink but with the "rebuild" option. That way the table should be emptied completely. This gives a weird error (*"Job failed due to reason: Conversion from StructType(StructField(data,StructType(StructField(id,StringType,true),.....* and that goes on for a couple of lines).

What would be the best way to clean out a CosmosDB table in Data Factory?

Comment: This question seems fairly broad, as there are many potential ways of deleting content from a Cosmos DB container (fyi Cosmos DB doesn't have *tables*).It's also a bit unclear, given that you haven't provided any specific example data at all. Cosmos DB has built-in TTL to age out old data, which may or may not help you. You could always manually delete documents with a specific status (e.g. for your tickets that are marked as `closed`). It doesn't need to be data factory doing this either (I'm not even sure data factory is the right tool for something like this).

Comment: @DavidMakogon since it's part of an automated process, Data Factory is the current tool of choice. If you know of a better option that can be triggered from Data Factory then I'm all ears.

TTL isn't an option since we want the option of running the batch more or less often. Manual deletion isn't an option either since it's an automated process. Specific status isn't an option since I only receive open tickets.

The question really isn't all that broad. Example data won't add information to the question. It all boils down to: Can I clear all data out of a container using Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm aware, this cannot be done just with ADF. You need to combine it with something like a logic app, databricks notebook or Azure function.
You can have a look at [this](https://azuredatageeks.com/2020/09/05/bulk-delete-documents-in-azure-cosmos-db-container-using-azure-data-factory/) article which shows the Logic app method. In this method you need to write a stored procedure which will delete the documents. The logic app just triggers that stored procedure. You can use an azure function to do this too.

Just to add, deleting using stored procedure will cost your RU/s. Using TTL will just use any left over un-used RU/s.

Comment: Then the best option I think is to delete and re-create the Container using an Azure Function Activity.